# How can I retrieve a domain computer's details from AWS Directory Service?

Tags: active-directory, amazon-web-services, powershell, aws-directory-service

I know using the AD module for powershell that we can retrieve domain computers details and export them as csv. My domain is in AWS Directory Service, and I have a computer under this domain. I tried `Get-ADComputer`, but it shows this error:

```
Get-ADComputer : Unable to find a default server with Active Directory Web Services running.
```

Is there another way that I can retrieve a domain computer's list in AWS Directory Service domain?

Comment: You may have to use `Get-ADDomainController` to find a server name for a domain controller and then specify it using the `-Server` parameter in `Get-ADComputer`.

Comment: Powershell : dsquery Computer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simple AD from AWS Directory Service doesn't support communication via PowerShell. This is because Simple AD is based on Samba4 which, in turn, doesn't support communication via PowerShell directly.

As mentioned in another thread, you can use the AWS APIs to do some basic operation like describing directories you currently have running in AWS from PowerShell cmdlets, but you can't actually query computers in your directory.

You'll have to use different directory administration tools to manage your Simple AD. You'll find more information in the documentation for AWS Directory Service about how to manage your directory with additional tools. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/directoryservice/latest/adminguide/directory_management.html

Comment: Ok.. That makes sense. But does that mean there's no way to query directory service to list or show the domain joined computers (using any scripting language).?

Comment: If you have a server that has the AD tools installed and joined to the domain then you can get the list of computers in your domain from powershell using : "dsquery computer"

Answer (score 0):

AWS has their own [set of cmdlets for the AWS Directory Service](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/powershell/latest/reference/items/AWS_Directory_Service_cmdlets.html) that you may be able to use in concert with the AD module.

Of particular interest is [Get-DSDirectory](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/powershell/latest/reference/items/Get-DSDirectory.html), which returns a [DirectoryDecription](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/latest/apidocs/items/TDirectoryServiceDirectoryDescription_NET3_5.html) object with the property `AccessUrl` for the directory.